# BeginReceiveFrom desn't catch packages from/to other devices

Tags: c#, sockets, packet-sniffers

I am trying to do package sniffer in C# and I want to write it on my own, using only C# methods to be not dependent of other authors. I am using method BeginReceiveFrom, and I catch only packages to/from device in LAN (192.168.0.87) and two addresses: 224.0.0.251:5353, 255.255.255.255:57621. Of course on device in LAN I opened websites to be sure there packages are going through network. What I do wrong? :-) every help appreciated!

1. I changed rules on firewall to not block my app.
2. I grant Administrator permissions to my app.
3. I changed method from BeginRecive to BeginReciveFrom.

static void Sniff(IPAddress ip) {

```
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, 0));
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
        sck.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, null);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[24];

        Action<IAsyncResult> OnReceive = null;
        EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.87"), 0);

        OnReceive = (ar) =>
        {
            String sourceIp = SourceIP(buffer);
            String destinationIp = DestinationIp(buffer);

            if (sourceIp != ip.ToString() && destinationIp != ip.ToString())
            {

                Console.WriteLine( 
                    "{0}\t{1}:{2}\t===>\t{3}:{4}"
                    , buffer.Skip(9).First().ToProtocolString()
                    , SourceIP(buffer)
                    , ((ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 20))).ToString()
                    , DestinationIp(buffer)
                    , ((ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 22))).ToString());
            }

            buffer = new byte[24]; //clean out our buffer

            //sck.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 24, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 24, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null); 
        };


        // sck.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    }

    private static String SourceIP(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return new IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 12)).ToString();
    }

    private static String DestinationIp(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return new IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 16)).ToString();
    }


    public static string ToProtocolString(this byte b)
    {
        switch (b)
        {
            case 1: return "ICMP";
            case 6: return "TCP";
            case 17: return "UDP";
            default: return "#" + b.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I see only few packages from/to addresses 224.0.0.251:5353, 255.255.255.255:57621. I expected to see whole communication from/to device in LAN.

Comment: IP protocol doesn't operate on ports so it's unclear what you mean by 224.0.0.251:5353 address and especially it's unclear what is 255.255.255.255:57621 address. Apart from that in order to get packages on the application level the network adapter should be in promiscuous mode. Additionally if your subnet is served by switch your device won't receive traffic intended for other devices so you cannot sniff in that case.

Comment: @Dmytro Mukalov thank you very much! I think problem is promiscuous mode. If I understand good code I wrote, this mode should be forced by IOControl method. Because Wire Shark doesn't catch packages too, I think problem is network adapter. I will buy one which allow me to set promiscuous mode and try again. Thank you once more!